# есть мнение, что просак имеет другое значение

Tags: лексика

в старину мужики баловались с девками на сеновале и попадали свои половым органом в часть тела девки между ее половыми органами и анальным отверстием.это место в простонароде называлось -просак.и так значение "попасть в просак"значит попасть не туда.вопрос правда ли это?